# Show only the first instance of a changepoint label in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame like this

```
GROUP <- c("PRE_ANALYSIS","PRE_ANALYSIS","BEFORE","AFTER","AFTER","AFTER","AFTER","AFTER","AFTER","AFTER","AFTER")
PDATETIME <- c("2016-11-23 06:08:39","2017-02-25 15:31:50","2017-04-06 17:11:57","2017-04-15 01:23:51 CDT",
               "2017-04-16 15:54:35","2017-04-16 23:48:14","2017-04-18 02:57:41","2017-04-20 05:12:33 CDT",
               "2017-04-20 14:33:20","2017-04-22 12:33:44","2017-04-23 10:50:49")
DELTA <- c(766.3770,863.8409,893.1615,656.1001,832.9232,912.3867,934.9714,-64.7182,460.3154,949.2538,697.3750)

df <- data.frame(GROUP,PDATETIME,DELTA) 
df$PDATETIME <- as.POSIXct(df$PDATETIME,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

I am trying to create a new column "IsChangePoint" which has the value

```
"CP Detected" for the first changepoint, the first index of df$GROUP = "AFTER"
```

I am trying to do it this way

```
df$IsChangepoint <- ifelse(df$GROUP == "AFTER", "CP Detected", "No")
```

and then getting this plot

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
ggplot(data = df, aes(PDATETIME,DELTA ))+ 
  ggtitle("Changepoint Analysis") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust=1),plot.title = element_text(size = rel(1))) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour=df$GROUP), size = 6) +
  geom_text_repel(aes(PDATETIME, DELTA, label = df$IsChangepoint)) +
  labs(colour="GROUP") + 
  xlab("PDATETIME")+ 
  ylab("DELTA")
```

[image]

This labels all the indexes after the changepoint. How can I plot the first instance of "CP DETECTED"?

**Desired Plot:** 
[image]

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `PRE_ANALYSIS` has text not only with the first instance. You want only first instance in `AFTER`?

Comment: @PoGibas yes exactly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want IsChangepoint to take on 1 of 3 values:

1. GROUP != "AFTER": "No" (**Edit** based on OP's comment: this should be blank too)
2. GROUP == "AFTER" & 1st row within this group: "CP Detected"
3. GROUP == "AFTER" & not 1st row within this group: "" (blank)

If that's the case, the following will give you that in the dataset:

```
df <- df %>% 
  arrange(PDATETIME) %>%
  group_by(GROUP) %>% mutate(IsChangepoint = row_number() == 1) %>% ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(IsChangepoint = ifelse(GROUP == "AFTER" & IsChangepoint, "CP Detected", ""))
```

Your original ggplot code works with this for me, though I think there's really no need to put `df$` in the `geom_text_repel()` call...

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(PDATETIME,DELTA ))+ 
  ggtitle("Changepoint Analysis") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust=1),plot.title = element_text(size = rel(1))) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour=df$GROUP), size = 6) +
  geom_text_repel(aes(PDATETIME, DELTA, label = IsChangepoint)) +
  labs(colour="GROUP") + 
  xlab("PDATETIME")+ 
  ylab("DELTA")
```

[image: updated plot]

Comment: Fantastic solution. Thank you :)